# ChartJS: problem with height when data size is too small

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm using ChartJS: 3.9.1 + react-chartjs-2: 4.3.1
I have a problem, when dataset is too small (2-3 values) - there is too much space between bars (see a picture):

[image]

This problem is not reproducible, when dataset have enough values:

[image]

My dataset:

```
barChartData = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      data: values,
      backgroundColor: '#F5CB3E',
      // barThickness: 17,
      borderRadius: 5,
      categoryPercentage: 1.0,
      barPercentage: 0.5,
      minBarLength: 1,
      yAxisID: 'y',
    },
  ],
};
```

My options:

```
 {
maintainAspectRatio: false,
responsive: true,
indexAxis: 'y',
plugins: {
  legend: {
    display: false,
    position: 'top' as const,
  },
  title: {
    display: false,
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  datalabels: {
    display: true,
    color: '#f2f2f2',
    formatter: Math.round,
    anchor: 'end',
    align: function (context: DataSetContext) {
      const data = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
      if (data < 10) {
        return 'start';
      } else {
        return 'end';
      }
    },
    offset: function (context: DataSetContext) {
      return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] < 10 ? -20 : 3;
    },
    clamp: true,
    font: {
      size: 14,
      weight: 600,
    },
  },
},
scales: {
  x: {
    stacked: true,
    grid: {
      display: false,
      drawBorder: false,
    },
    ticks: {
      font: { size: 13 },
      color: '#f0f0f0',
      display: false,
    },
    suggestedMax: (1 + 0.2) * configurableOptions.xAxisMaxValue,
  },
  y: {
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: false,
      color: '#f0f0f0',
      font: {
        size: 14,
        weight: 500,
      },
    },
    grid: {
      drawBorder: false,
      display: false,
    },
  },
},
```

};

I dancing with barPercentage and categoryPercentage but nothing has changed. Seems documentation doesn't contains the answer on my questions. I want to have always the same distance between bars and the same bars thickness, regardless of dataset size
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You set the property `maxBarThickness` in your dataset, this prohibits the bar from becoming wider.

You either need to remove this property or change the size of the canvas so your bars are getting closer to eachother.

Comment: Removed maxBarThickness, bar becoming winder, but how can I change the height of canvas? So that the bars are always the same thickness and there is always the same distance between them? Regardless of the amount of data transferred, so that it works both in a big way, when there is a lot of data, and in a smaller direction, when there is very little data?

Answer (score 0):

try barPercentage: 1
for setting the gap of bars

Comment: It's not working, because if you will have more than 20 bars, it doesn't fix a problem

Comment: @artyom.poteshkin98 i see, disnt notice you got 20+ bars, maybe the font size of the dataset labels got something to do with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally bit this. Maybe, this solution isn't good and, of course, you can improve it, but it works for my case:

```
 <Box>
  <Box className={classes.chartBoxWrapper}>
    <Box className={classes.chartBox}>
      {barChartData && options && dataSize > 0 && (
        <Bar options={options} data={barChartData} />
      )}
    </Box>
  </Box>
  {dataSize > 10 && (
    <Box position="relative">
      <Box className={classes.shadowBox}></Box>
    </Box>
  )}
</Box>
```

and CSS:

```
chartBox: {
  borderRadius: '9px',
  height: ({ dataSize }: { dataSize: number }) => {
    if (dataSize === 0) {
      return '40px';
    } else {
      return `${dataSize * (40 - dataSize / 3)}px`;
    }
  },
},

chartBoxWrapper: {
  height: ({ dataSize }: { dataSize: number }) => {
    if (dataSize === 0) {
      return '40px';
    } else if (dataSize > 10) {
      return '315px';
    } else {
      return `${dataSize * (40 - dataSize / 4)}px`;
    }
  },
  overflowY: ({ dataSize }: { dataSize: number }) =>
    dataSize > 10 ? 'scroll' : 'initial',
},

shadowBox: {
  position: 'absolute',
  bottom: -3,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  background: 'linear-gradient(0deg, #232323 0%, rgba(35, 35, 35, 0) 100%)',
  height: '35px',
},
```

I just dynamically increase chart height and when size is greater than 10, simply add overflow and set fixed height = 315px.